# getting wrong CropBox rect in this PDF i will get like (-396,-306,792,612)?

Tags: ios

Are there some issue with this pdf ?
what to do to get rid of this ?

here is my sample code

```
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(drawPDFPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, angle, true));
    appdel.widthScale=scale;
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); 

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, cropBoxRect);
    //CGContextClipToRect(context, cropBoxRect);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, drawPDFPageRef);
```

Pdf name is Xoom Pad 4.pdf

http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Support/US-EN/TABLETS/XOOM-with-Wi-Fi/Documents/StaticFiles/XOOM_wifi_GSG_US_68016036001A.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's certainly possible that the cropbox has negative values from pdf coordinate space.

Comment: WHat will i do for this case my annotation on this PDF not working :(